# Why the value of biased exponent is 127 instead of 128?

Tags: floating-point, exponent

I know this question is too common (or boring) with you. But, I don't understand why 127 is chosen as bias exponent, instead of 128.

As IEEE-754 standard, we have 8 bits for exponent part for floating-point numbers. As I known, with 8 bits of integers, we'll have a range:

- [-128,127] for signed integers
- or [0,255] for unsigned integers

OK, right now, in order to shift (or bias), normally we must to add 128 to signed integers to convert them to unsigned integers. For example,

- -128 + 128 = 0
- -127 + 128 = 1

But, the IEEE-754 standard select 127 as bias whereas as -128 + 127 = - 1 < 0. Is it logic ?

I clearly don't understand the reason behind. Therefore, I need your help and thank you for everyone.

Comment: *"OK, right now, in order to shift (or bias), normally we must to add 128 to signed integers to convert them to unsigned integers."* Must we? That seems completely arbitrary operation. I don't remember seeing need for such operation in real world applications. Typically signed integer is converted to unsigned by adding 256 until value is in range 0..255.

Comment: So, what is the reason to chose 127 instead of 128 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen a quote, perhaps in one of Kahan's documents, explaining that the exponent bias was adjusted in IEEE-754 (relative to what it had been in some earlier floating-point formats, such as DEC's) in order to achieve some desirable property, such that numbers and their reciprocals were more balanced or symmetrically representable, or something.  I can't quite remember, but I'm sure someone else here does.

Comment: @SteveSummit True.  A key benefit was using those small de-normal/subnormals to get around the conundrum of having `1.0/normal` in the [some_min ... max], something problematic without those wee values.  Unlike, for example [IBM hexadecimal floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_hexadecimal_floating-point#Largest_representable_number)

Comment: See [my answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131949/logic-behind-choosing-the-exponent-bias-as-27-1-instead-of-27-in-32-bit) at Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: @njuffa great :). I would like to say thank you very much :) (+1 upvote for your answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why 127 is chosen as bias exponent, instead of 128.

The bias selection for [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is not concerned with *signed* to *unsigned* integer conversion.

The choice is based on desired range of the floating point encoding.

```
max           3.402...e+38
min normal    1.175...e-38
min subnormal 1.401...e-45
```

The bias selection is somewhat arbitrary.  To achieve a balanced range, with the bias of 127, 1.0/max is non-zero (some subnormal exponentially near min normal) and 1.0/min_normal is <= max.  These are nice properties.  All 1.0/normal are within binary32 non-zero finite range.

With a bias of 128, those values would be half as much and we would lose that 1.0/min_normal is <= max property.

Comment: Deeper: "As I known, with 8 bits of integers, we'll have a range:" --> note that at the time of first IEEE 754 (1985), non-2's complement machines still existed and "[-128,127] for signed integers" was not as universal as today.  Sometimes it was "[-127,127] for signed integers".  I suspect this is a contributor reason for a _biased_ _unsigned_ exponent field and not a signed encoded one favoring one of the 3 signed integer encoding schemes.  Biased unsigned has other features too - but we are deep enough.

Comment: one more reason (but I'm not sure 100%), 127 is the median of range [0,255]. So, they used 127 to ensure that : 
- the range [1,126] express the negative of [-126, -1]
- the range [128, 254] express the positive of [+1, +254]

I think but I'm not sure.

Comment: @locobe "127 is the median of range [0,255]" --> [an even number of values, as there is no single number which divides all of the numbers to two halves,](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

Comment: Basically, the range [0,255] has 256 values. But after exluding 0 and 255 (special cases) the range will be [1,254] or we have 254 values, so the "median" will be 127. Or as I said, 127 is chosen because the amount of elements of two sets (0,127) and (128, 255) will be balanced (it means, we have 128 elements for each sets).
I'm sorry if my explanation is not correct.

Comment: > The bias selection for binary32 is not concerned with signed to unsigned integer conversion.
It means that we don't apply the Two's Complement for exponent of floating-point, right ?

Comment: @locobe Yes, the 8-bit unsigned biased exponent is converted to a signed value by subtracting the bias.

Comment: OK, let's me paraphrase your comment. 8-bits integers signed (using 2's complement) has the range [-128,+127], and 8-bits integers of exponent has the range [0,255] (usigned) or [-127,+128] (signed). It seems to be quite similar but different (easy to confuse). Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251860/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-locobe).